# Javascript - Extract a link from inside an html code

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to extract the link inside href and store it in a variable. Please see my code snippet below. Note that the token id is expected to be different with every single run.
Thank you for your help.

```
const body = <html><head></head><body><p>This is SignUp Email with confirmation link</p><p><a href = "http://www.company.com/ls/click?upn=tokenid-11111-22222-333333-444444-555555-xxxxxx"></a></p></body></html>
const activation_link = ???
console.log(activation_link)
/*
The expected result to be printed on Console:
"http://www.company.com/ls/click?upn=tokenid-11111-22222-333333-444444-555555-xxxxxx"
*/
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Is it how you define body or it's just a "representation" of what you have in the document? Asking because it's not proper way of doing it.

Comment: Following on from the comment above, if this is just an example of your document: Will there ever be multiple links on the page? and if so, how do you specify which URL you want?

Comment: @TheTanadu this is actually just a code snippet. My main concern is/was to find how to easily get a link from inside html body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const body = `<html><head></head><body><p>This is SignUp Email with confirmation link</p><p><a href = "http://www.company.com/ls/click?upn=tokenid-11111-22222-333333-444444-555555-xxxxxx"></a></p></body></html>`
const matched_links = body.match(/(?<=")http.+(?=")/);
console.log(matched_links);
```